# Not able to read the value from textbox in templatefield

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Region">
     <HeaderTemplate>                          
     <asp:Label ID="lblItem" Text='Region' runat="server"></asp:Label><br /><br />
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>                           
     <asp:Label ID="lblItem0" Text='<%# Eval("Region") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>                         
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is the C# code for the textbox

```
 TextBox q1 = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBox1");
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Region", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = q1.Text;
```

textbox always shows null value even though there is a value in textbox how to make the code value reconizable
Thanks in advance

Comment: In which event you want to get it?

Comment: I tried in button click event but not working

Comment: search is not happening inside the gridview but if i use the same textbox outside the gridview it is working